# Trouble replacing text with a dynamic string that contains $0

Tags: c#, regex

I am using `Regex` to replace all the strings in a template. Everything works fine until there is a value I want to replace, which is `$0.00`. I can't seem to properly replace the `$0` as replacement text. The output I am getting is `"Project Cost: [[ProjectCost]].00"`. Any idea why?

Here is an example of the code with some simplified variables.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Security;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Export.Services
{
    public class CommonExportService
    {

        private Dictionary<string, string> _formTokens;


        public CommonExportService() {
         _formTokens =     {{"EstimatedOneTimeProjectCost", "0.00"}};
        }


        private string GetReplacementText(string replacementText)
        {
            replacementText = "Project Cost: [[EstimatedOneTimeProjectCost]]";
            //replacement text = "Project Cost: [[ProjectCost]]"
            foreach (var token in _formTokens)
            {
                var val = token.Value;
                var key = token.Key;

                //work around for now
                //if (val.Equals("$0.00")) {
                //    val = "0.00";
                //}

                var reg = new Regex(Regex.Escape("[[" + key + "]]"));


                if (reg.IsMatch(replacementText))                        
                    replacementText = reg.Replace(replacementText, SecurityElement.Escape(val ?? string.Empty));
                else {

                }
            }

            return replacementText;

            //$0.00 does not replace,  something is happening with the $0 before the decimal  
            //the output becomes Project Cost: [[EstimatedOneTimeProjectCost]].00


            //The output is correct for these
            //0.00 replaces correctly
            //$.00 replaces correctly
            //0 replaces correctly
            //00 replaces correctly
            //$ replaces correctly

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write a [MCVE]?

Comment: @aloisdg I have edited the question with a minimal class example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your replacement string is built dynamically, you need to take care of the `$` char in it. When `$` is followed with `0`, the `$0` is a backreference to the whole match, so the whole match is inserted as a result of replacement.

You just need to dollar-escape the `$` inside a literal string pattern:

```
return replacementText.replace("$", "$$");
```

Then, your replacement pattern will contain `$$0`, and that will "translate" into a literal `$0` string.